# Log off Remote Desktop Session on a non admin account programmatically

Tags: c#, winapi, remote-desktop

I am making a tool that displays all the Remote Desktop Sessions and look for a spesific process and show if that process is running on that session. And i need to log off a user. I launch the application by right clicking and selecting "run as admin", i can't set requestedExecutionLevel to admin because when you don't have admin rights you still have the ability to see all the sessions.

I first tried this to disconnect a session(but it only works when i run the application on a admin account, so right clicking and selecting "run as admin" doesn't work):

```
static public bool LogOff(string SessionID)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C logoff " + SessionID;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    process.Start();
    return true;
}
```

Next i tried using this(this also only works when the account i'm running the application on is admin):

```
static public bool LogOff(string SessionID)
{
    if (WTSLogoffSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, int.Parse(SessionID), true))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

My question is, is there any way i can disconnect a session when i run this program on a user account while selecting "run as admin"?

Comment: oh oke, so if i "run as admin" i don't have enough rights to log other users out?

Comment: No, that should work - assuming that the user feeds in an administrative username and password at the authentication prompt.  Sorry, I had misread the question.  So what goes wrong?  What error code is returned?

Comment: The problem is when i launch the program while selecting "Run as admin", i can't log a users session off. But that's strange because the program has admin rights(when i check with WindowsPrincipal, it tells me i have admin rights). And it doesn't return any errors.